# Как получить координаты мышки в javascript без jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, координаты

Скиньте пожалуйста самый простой пример с двумя input, в которых будут обновляться координаты мышки по горизонтали и вертикали.
Без jQuery , спасибо )

Answer (score 4):

Используя [mouse event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp). Простейший пример ниже.

```js
var X = document.getElementById('X');
var Y = document.getElementById('Y');

function pos(e){
  X.value = e.pageX;
  Y.value = e.pageY;
}

addEventListener('mousemove', pos, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="X">
<input type="text" id="Y">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал для вас пример с двумя инпутами, в которых обновляются координаты.

```js
let handleMousemove = (event) => {
  //console.warn(`${event.x}:${event.y}`);
  document.getElementById("x").value = `\n${event.x}`;
  document.getElementById("y").value = `\n${event.y}`;
};

let throttle = (func, delay) => {
  let prev = Date.now() - delay;

  return (...args) => {
    let current = Date.now();
    if (current - prev >= delay) {
      prev = current;
      func.apply(null, args);
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', throttle(handleMousemove, 500));
```

```html
move mouse here
<input type="text" id="x">
<input type="text" id="y">
```

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/178nz54o/
```

Comment: Тут лучше не тротл, а дебаунс использовать. Проведите быстро мышкой — будут показаны не те координаты, на которых мышка находится.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, debounce тут будет гораздо лучше, нежели throttle :)

Answer (score 1):

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Пример для clientX\clientY</title>

<script>
function showCoords(evt){
  alert(
    "clientX value: " + evt.clientX + "\n" +
    "clientY value: " + evt.clientY + "\n"
  );
}
</script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="showCoords(event)">
<p>Для показа координат мышки нажмите в любом месте страницы.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Вместо alert поставьте value Ваших 2 input

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так

```js
var IE = document.all ? true : false;
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
var tempX = 0;
var tempY = 0;

function getMouseXY(e) {
  if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  } else { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
    tempX = e.pageX;
    tempY = e.pageY;
  }
  if (tempX < 0) {
    tempX = 0;
  }
  if (tempY < 0) {
    tempY = 0;
  }
  document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;
  document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="Show">
  X <input type="text" name="MouseX" value="0" size="4"><br> Y <input type="text" name="MouseY" value="0" size="4"><br>
</form>
```